# Using Active Record, how can I save child's detail information through its parent?

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I'm using parent->child (master->detail) relation in Yii2 Active Record

When I want to create a child, I have to manually fill its parent info like this:

> Relation: Client (1) ---> (n) Comments

```
class ClientController extends \yii\web\Controller
{

    public function actionAddComment() {
        $comment = new Comment;
        if ($comment->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $comment->client = $this->id;  // Client id
            $comment->save();
        }
        return $this->render('view', ['comment'=>$comment]);

    }
}
```

I've optimized it, creating a Comment method to do that:

```
class Comment extends ActiveRecord {

    public function newComment($client) {
        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->client = $client;  // Client id
        return $comment;
    }
}
```

And I have gone through beforeSave in the Comment model, but still not sure if there is a better way.

Is there anything like:

```
$comment = new Comment(Yii::$app->request->post());
$client->save($comment);  // Here the parent is writing his information to the child
```

Or one-liner shortcut:

```
$client->save(new Comment(Yii::$app->request->post());
```

Without having to create this logic in beforeSave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I recommend to use the built in `link()` and `unlink()` methods provided by Active Record which you can use in your controller to relate or unrelate 2 models either they share many-to-many or one-to-many relationship.

It even has an optional $extraColumns attribute for additional column values to be saved into a junction table if using it `link( $name, $model, $extraColumns = [] )`

So your code may look like this :

```
$comment = new Comment;
if ($comment->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $comment->link('client', $this);
}
```

check [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#saving-relations) for more info.

Now about where to use this code to relate models, it depend on how your app is structured. I'm not sure if doing that through a triggered event would be a good practice, you need to remember that errors may happens and 
you may need to evaluate certain scenarios or logic before throwing exceptions. So in my case, I prefer to use that code into my Controllers.

Sometimes you need to build a specific action like you did `actionAddComment()`, In certain other cases like when your Post request is meant to update the Parent model and also update its related child models at once, the Parent's Update Action `ClientController::actionUpdate()` may be a good place to do so, maybe something like this will do the job :

```
$params = Yii::$app->request->post();

$client->load($this->params, '');
if ($client->save() === false && !$client->hasErrors()) {
    throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Failed to update the object for unknown reason.');
}

foreach ($params["comments"] as $comment) {
  // We may be sure that both models exists before linking them.
  // In this case I'm retrieving the child model from db so I don't
  // have to validate it while i just need its id from the Post Request
  $comment = Comment::findOne($comment['id']);
  if (!$comment) throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Failed to update due to unknown related objects.');
  // according to its documentation, link() method will throw an exception if unable to link the two models.
  $comment->link('client', $client);     
  ...
```